# Ordenar un Array JSON en un Tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, array, html-tabla

tengo un arreglo de medidas, pueden ser de 2 a n medidas las cuales tengo en un JSON ademas este grupo de medidas cuentan con nombre y una fecha.

```
[
    {
        "nombre": "longitud total",
        "fecha": "2019-04-01",
        "medidas": [ 0.8220, 0.8220, 0.8230, 0.8226, 0.8229, 0.8228, 0.8209, 0.8224, 0.8225, 0.8219, 0.8227 ]
    },
    {
        "nombre": "longitud total",
        "fecha": "2019-04-03",
        "medidas": [ 0.8204, 0.8223, 0.8225, 0.8210, 0.8229, 0.8205, 0.8226, 0.8226, 0.8211, 0.8221 ]
    },
    {
        "nombre": "longitud total",
        "fecha": "2019-04-02",
        "medidas": [ 0.8207, 0.8215, 0.8222, 0.8209, 0.8207, 0.8215, 0.8226, 0.822, 0.8209, 0.8229 ]
    }
]
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenar estas medidas por fecha en subgrupos de 5 de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo: Si capturo *20 medidas* el día 2019-03-02 y *10 medidas* el día 2019-04-03, se deberán vaciar en la tabla 4 grupos de 5 medidas para la primera fecha y 2 grupos de 5 medidas para la segunda fecha, (la fecha se repite).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

** HTML **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Operaciones DTI</title>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <br>
    <h2 class="text-center">Operaciones aritmeticas y logica para procesar las medidas</h2>
    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="section">

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="boton">Importar XLS</button><br><br>

            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>SubGrupo</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Medidas</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="respuesta">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

** JavaScript **

```
// console.log('Correcto');

document.querySelector('#boton').addEventListener('click', traerDatos);

function traerDatos(){
    // console.log('Dentro de la función');

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', 'poblacion.json', true);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            // console.log(this.responseText);
            let medidas = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // se aplica parse para JSON
            //console.log(medidas);
            // Declaramos la variable para la respuesta
            let res = document.querySelector('#respuesta');
            respuesta.innerHTML = '';

            // Ordenar por fecha
            medidas.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.fecha) > new Date(b.fecha));

            // Mostrar datos
            for(let item of medidas){
                //console.log(item);
                respuesta.innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>${item.nombre}</td>
                        <td>${item.fecha}</td>
                        <td>${item.medidas.sort()}</td>
                    </tr>
                `
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no logro entender con exactitud que es lo que deseas realizar, podrías dar una mejor explicación y resaltar la cuestión en si

Comment: quiero ordenar las medidas del arreglo en grupos de 5 ordenados por fecha en una tabla html, al parecer es una matriz, gracias @nauseantparrot